# Subversion : get file's history from files in .svn directory?

Tags: svn, history

Is there any way to access file's history using the data in the .svn directory directly?  The files I have a copied from a a server that was taken down a long time ago, so there is no SVN server running.  All I have are the current files and what's in the .svn directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all the history is kept on the server.  .svn contains information only about your working copy. If your working copy in SVN 1.7 format you may examine the information you have manually using SQLite (.svn/wc.db is SQLite database). For instance, you may use this database browser: http://sqljet.com/browser/browser.jnlp